# Getting name of the exception along with the error

Tags: python, error-handling

How to get the name of the exception in `try..except` block of Python?

```
try:
    #code that throws errors
except Exception as e:
    #A broad except block to catch all errors
    #Handling the error
```

Sometimes when there are a lot of exceptions to handle, catching `Exception` seems easy (though discouraged). But I'm not able to find the name of the exception, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `print(type(e))` or just `print(e)`?

Comment: Oops.. just print(e). Isnt it a string?

Comment: `print(e)` will print the string representation of the exception, `print(type(e))` will print the class of the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by "name" you mean "type", try `type(e)` in your `except` block.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
type(e).__name__
```

Or

```
type(e).__class__.name
```

Or

```
type(e).__class__.qualname
```

Comment: Exceptions do not have an attribute `__name__` - `type(e).__name__` would work however

Comment: All the three didn't work. `AttributeError`. :) But hey, `e.__name__` works (its same as `type(e)` I suppose?)

Comment: No not quite same.....

Comment: Oops sorry. Thought `type` returns `__name__` of an object.